Exposing files of docker-image in jupyter hub not working?
I want yo build a jupyter-hub that can start jupyter-notebooks that have some content-baked in. I use docker spawning to start the server.
This is part of my Dockerfile that is building on jupyter/base-notebook
FROM jupyter/base-notebook
[...]
# ($HOME = /home/jovyan, $NB_USER=jovyan)
# Switch to non-privileged user
WORKDIR ${HOME}

RUN mkdir ${HOME}/start

# Copy application files
COPY --chown=${NB_USER}:${NB_USER} ./tutorial.ipynb ${HOME}/start/tutorial.ipynb
COPY --chown=${NB_USER}:${NB_USER} ./tutorial_files ${HOME}/start/tutorial_files

In my config for the jupyter-hub, I have this in my docker-compose.yml:
services:
  jupyterhub:
    image: ghcr.io/data2act/ai_jupyterhub:latest
    ...
    volumes:
      - "./docker-config.json:/root/.docker/config.json:ro"
      - "./jupyterhub_config.py:/srv/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py:ro"
    ...
    environment:
      JUPYTERHUB_ADMIN: "admin"
      # JupyterHub will spawn this Notebook image for users
      # Notebook directory inside user image
      DOCKER_NOTEBOOK_DIR: /home/jovyan

I mount the config file, which has this:
# Explicitly set notebook directory because we'll be mounting a volume to it.
# Most `jupyter/docker-stacks` *-notebook images run the Notebook server as
# user `jovyan`, and set the notebook directory to `/home/jovyan/work`.
# We follow the same convention.
notebook_dir = os.environ.get("DOCKER_NOTEBOOK_DIR", "/home/jovyan")
c.DockerSpawner.notebook_dir = notebook_dir

# Mount the real user's Docker volume on the host to the notebook user's
# notebook directory in the container
c.DockerSpawner.volumes = {
    "standalone-jupyterhub-user-{username}": notebook_dir,
    "/usr/local/docker/standalone_jupyterhub/shared": "/home/jovyan/work/shared"
}
c.DockerSpawner.prefix = "standalone_jupyterhub"

If I run the docker image as a separate container from the command line with docker run, I get my files where I expect them. However, running in the hub seems to hide the files in the docker image? There is no folder start?

It looks like your code adds a volume mount over /home/joyvan.  That will hide everything in the image in that directory, including what the image has copied into /home/joyvan/start.

@DavidMaze it seems the UI is chrooted to this dir. I can start at for example /home/joyvan/work but how do I allow the user to navigate back to /home/joyvan ?
